# How do you remove read-only files with grunt clean?

Tags: build-automation, gruntjs

I have a grunt build script which has a `clean` task to remove some cache files. Currently this task fails because the files it is supposed to remove are read-only.

**How do you make `grunt clean` remove read-only files?**

For those who are curious, the output from my command is as follows:

```
Running "clean:templates" (clean) task
Verifying property clean.templates exists in config...OK
Files: app/cache/dev/twig, app/cache/prod/twig -> templates
Options: force
Cleaning "app/cache/dev/twig"...Deleting app/cache/dev/twig...ERROR
ERROR
>> Error: Unable to delete "app/cache/dev/twig" file (EPERM, operation not permitted 'app/cache/dev/twig').
Warning: Clean operation failed. Use --force to continue.
```

The files in the `app/cache/dev/twig` folder are read-only and can be deleted with the command `rm -rf app/cache/dev/twig`.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way, but if you have sufficient permissions try:
https://github.com/JamesMGreene/grunt-chmod + grunt-contrib-clean?

```
chmod: {
  options: {
  mode: '755'
  },
  yourTarget1: {
   src: ['**/*.js']
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try this as a workaround however I get the same access denied errors. I think that this is because I am attributed permissions to the files through ACL entries.